# Pyramid SQLAlchemy database changes disappear on reload

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I just started building my webapp, working from the pyramid tutorials.

When I add an item to my database, it gets persisted correctly, but when I change something in pyramid and need to restart the server

`$VENV/bin/pserve development.ini --reload`

all my changes are lost. Does anyone know why this happens?

I changed the initialize_db.py script to build a demo database, and changed the sessionmaker to

`session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension('changed')))`

I've tried `session.commit()` and `session.flush()`, with no luck.

Comment: which tutorial are you following?

Comment: The quick tutorial http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/index.html, superficially. I've done it before so I'm just using it as a base to get started.

Comment: I use ORM, but your answer was correct, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to also have the `pyramid_tm` (transaction manager) configured; it is the one that *actually* commits the changes. Now it seems like you're not committing the changes / are just reusing the same dirty uncommitted session from request to another.

E.g. if you follow the [`wiki2`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/index.html), it [assumes](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/installation.html#decisions-the-alchemy-scaffold-has-made-for-you) that you created the minimal project with `pcreate` using the `alchemy` scaffold.

In any case, make sure that the [`development.ini` that you're using contains](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/databases.html)

```
pyramid.includes =
    pyramid_debugtoolbar
    pyramid_tm                 <--- this here
```

Comment: It sounds possible, but I did use the alchemy scaffold to get started. How can I check `pyramid_tm` is not configured?

Comment: Indeed, I didn't have `pyramid_tm` in there. It must have gotten lost when I was cannibalising the tutorial. Thanks!